# Django how to create session variables to pass information from one web page to another

Tags: python, html, mysql, django, django-templates

I'm new to django session. If I have pieces of information extracted in one page view such as this

```
    if 'editEntry' in request.POST:

        values = request.POST['editEntry']
        values = values.split(',')
        id_num = values[0]
        first_name = values[1]
        last_name = values[2]
        country = values[3]
        city = values[4]
        salary = values[5]

        return redirect('/edit')
```

Is there a way to send those variable information to another webpage? Also what would the template language be to call on a variable like id_num in the html file.

Comment: `request.session` is what you're looking for. To set variable, just do like `request.session['key']=value`

Comment: How would I then pass it on in the second webpage?

Comment: you can retrieve any values passed in session with `request.session['key']`, in template: `{{ request.session.key }}`